# Three.js: PointerLockControls somehow change the position of stencil

Tags: three.js, stencil-buffer, pointerlock

I'm using the stencil buffer to composite two THREE.js Scenes over each other. This works, but when I try to use PointerLockControls, moving the camera (using mouse or keyboard) somehow causes the stenciled part of the view to be moved/shifted. It seems to lag behind the camera position.

I've tried other controls (Trackball, Orbit), and this issue does not occur when using those.

Something seems to be clashing, but I have no idea where to look.

The PointerLock code is copied straight from the [examples](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_pointerlock).

This is the render code:

```
// 1: clear scene (autoClear is disabled)
renderer.clear(true, true, true);

// 2: draw portal mesh into stencil buffer
gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false);
gl.depthMask(false);
gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
gl.stencilMask(0xFF);
gl.stencilFunc(gl.NEVER, 0, 0xFF);
gl.stencilOp(gl.INCR, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP);

renderer.render(stencilScene, camera);

gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);
gl.depthMask(true);
gl.stencilOp(gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP);

// 3: draw toScene on scencil
renderer.clear(false, true, false);

gl.stencilFunc(gl.LESS, 0, 0xff);

renderer.render(toScene, camera);

gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);

renderer.clear(false, false, true);

// clear the depth buffer and draw the fromPortal mesh into it
renderer.clear(false, true, false);

gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false);
gl.depthMask(true);

renderer.render(stencilScene, camera);

// draw the actual scene
gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);
gl.depthMask(false); // gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST) ?

renderer.render(fromScene, camera);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g8EWG/

If you move from left to right, or just look around, the shift is quite noticeable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear to me what it _should_ look like... But my guess is that the problem has to do with the fact that in pointer lock controls, the camera is a child of two rotated parent objects. The camera's world position/rotation is likely not being taken into consideration.